# Excel VB Cell finder macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm programming a macro in VB in Excel,  that will find a filled (not empty) cell from a table of cells/ from a range.
I know a little C++, but I don't think it would be too hard to make a little macro in VB.

The problem here is that the macro doesn't find the filled cell, but just skips it. What have I done wrong?

```
Sub Datum()
Dim Horizontal As Integer
Horizontal = 10

Dim Vertical As Integer
Vertical = 10

Dim h As Integer
Dim v As Integer
h = 0
v = 0

Range("A1").Select


For v = 0 To Vertical

    For h = 0 To Horizontal
        If ActiveCell.Value = True Then
            Exit For
            Exit For
            End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

    Next

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

h = 0
Next

MsgBox ActiveCell.Value


End Sub
```

ps. I HAVE researched on the internet, but it seems like none have this problem as I do.

Comment: Guess but try a string comparison; `If ActiveCell.Value = "True" `

Comment: True is a boolean. "True" is a string.  Try IsEmpty(cell).

Comment: Forget your macro for a moment. What are the contents of the cell you want to find? Try `ActiveCell.Value` in the Immediate window. Does it return True for that cell? Try `Typename(ActiveCell.Value)`. What type is it? Is it boolean? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be selecting each cell because this is very time consuming.  This does not matter if your range is 10*10 but I assume this is an experiment.

This code replaces your loop.  I have used your variables.

```
Dim Found as Boolean

Found = False

With ActiveSheet

  For v = 1 to vertical
    For h = 1 to horizontal
      If IsEmpty(.Cells(v, h).Value) Then
        Found = True
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
    If Found then
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  If Found Then
    ' Action empty cell (v,h) found in range
  Else
    ' Action no empty cell in range
  End If
```

In this experiment your range is 10x10.  Do you know the true size?  Do you want to determine the used range at run time?  These issues will have to be addressed before we can provide a total solution.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem will be the looping I think:

```
Exit For
Exit For
```

This won't do what you want as the first command will jump you out of the inner `For` loop and you'll never hit the second one, so you'll carry on executing the outer for loop.

You'd possibly be better with Do-While type loops:

```
Dim blnFound as Boolean
Dim v as integer
dim h as integer
blnFound = false
v = 0
Do while v <= Vertical and not blnFound

    h = 0

    Do while h <= Horizontal and not blnFound
        If ActiveCell.Value = True Then
            blnFound = True
        End If

        h=h+1
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

    loop

    v = v+1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

loop
```

I also not sure that your `Offset` calls will do what you want, particularly around going to the top of the next column. You may be better to use the `v` and `h` values to select the cell to check more precisely (eg `ActiveSheet.Cell(h,v)`)

Note: I've not tested this code so it may need tweaking, but it should give an idea.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Your code is much more elegant than mine, but I guess that comes with time. I'll look at it and see if it works.